# Does Mortar Board badge ignore the Association Bonus?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, badges

I recently had a 220 rep day and did not get the badge, so i wanted to confirm that that was in fact the reason for it.

And while I'm on the topic, up-votes and accepted answers are the only two things that would contribute to that badge correct?

On a side note, does this fall under bug or support or discussion? I would think support but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[support](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support) is fine. :)

The association bonus does not affect the badge as you observed. This is by design.

Mortarboard is affected by

- upvotes on your questions
- upvotes on your answers
- acceptances of your answers
- bounties being awarded to your answers

See more info [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions).